# Simple IF Statement Not Working As It Should

Tags: python

Take a look at this working if statement (only with 1 string in the variable):

[It corrects me if I type "Nick"]

[image]

However, if I add more then 1 string to the wrongname varible, it breaks:

[After typing "Nick" it did not correct me]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
invalidname = True
wrongname = ["Nick", "Moni"]
while invalidname == True:
  name = input('Please enter your name: ')
  if name == wrongname:
    print("YOUR FULL NAME, don't be lazy.")
  if name != wrongname:
    print("Hello, " + name)
    break
```

I tried using a table of strings under 1 varible but it is not working with the if statement.

Comment: Change `name == wrongname` to `name in wrongname`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: As written, you're checking to see if the user's input is equal to *the list* `wrongname` which is `["Nick", "Moni"]` - so nothing the user enters will ever match. As @Barmar said, you should use `in` to test for membership in the list instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast comments. After trying this I get:

Please enter your name: Nick
YOUR FULL NAME, don't be lazy.
Hello, Nick

It just runs the 2nd if statement. But I don't want the 2nd if statement to run unless its NOT a wrongname.

Comment: The second should be `if name not in wrongname:` or simply `else:`

Comment: In that case, instead of a second `IF` use an `else` with no condition. An `else` will fire only if the `if` condition fails.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar that worked! Just practicing for my Python class coming up. Cheers!